# What is the right way to store counters in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

For example we need to store number of likes and shares of article. I see two options how to do it:

1. store them as embedded document

```
stats: {
    likes_count: 10,
    shares_count: 5
}
```

2. store each field as a regular field

```
title: "New car",
likes_count: 10,
shares_count: 5
```

Which option is more correct? Or it should be stored another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options work fine.

> Which option is more correct?

This is opinion based.